# Is there a way to save metadata on custom elements with Google Sheets & Slides Ad-ons?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-slides-api, google-slides

I am new to Google Ad-ons, and am looking for a way to place an image on a Google Slide or data into a Google Sheet. Then save metadata to that image or Google Sheet so that I can update the image or data when there is a new image or data available.

Is there way way to save metadata on custom elements (images / data) in order to refresh those elements?

Answer (score 0):

For slides, you can refer [here on how to add image to the slide](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/add-image).

> This page describes how to add images to an existing Google Slides
>   presentation. When adding an image, you provide the Slides API with a
>   publicly accessible URL to the image.

There are also available [sample codes](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/add-image#example) in the documentation.

For sheets, here is a [documentation on how you can add developer metadata](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/metadata).

> The Developer Metadata feature lets you associate metadata with
>   various entities and locations in a spreadsheet. You can then query
>   this metadata and use it to look up the objects with which it is
>   associated.
>
> Developer metadata lets you perform operations such as:
>
> - **Associate arbitrary data with various entities and locations in a    spreadsheet**. For example, associating "totals" with column D, or
>     "responseId -> 1234" with row 7.
> - **Look up all locations and data associated with a particular metadata    key or attribute**. For example, given the key "totals"
>     return that it    is associated with column D, or given "responseId"
>     return the set of    all rows with "responseId" metadata, and the
>     metadata value    associated with it.
> - **Look up all data associated with a particular entity or location**. For    example, given column D, return all metadata
>     associated with that    location.
> - **Retrieve values in a location by specifying associated metadata**. For    example, given "totals" return a representation of
>     the values    contained in the associated column or row; or given
>     "summary" return    a representation of the associated Sheet resource.
> - **Update values in a location by specifying associated metadata**. For    example, instead of updating values in a row by providing the
>     A1    range, update values by indicating a metadata ID.
>
> You can associate data with rows, columns, sheets, or the spreadsheet.

There is also available code in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/apps-script) as shown in the example.